# How can we register a CSV data migration dynamically?

Tags: 8, migrations, importing-exporting

I am trying to achieve CSV data migration like below:

**Requirement:**
CSV file will be pushed to our server on daily basis from other vendors. We have to fetch that particular CSV file and we need to migrate the CSV data into content to our website.

**Tried:** I installed [migrate source csv](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv), [migrate tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) and [migrate plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus).
I created a below YAML structure for the same and I imported through configuration synchronisation.

YAML structure:

```
langcode: en
status: true
id: article_csv_import
migration_group: default
label: 'Import articles'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'public://customfiles/file.csv'
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_offset: 0
  ids:
    - id
  fields:
    -
      name: id
      label: 'Unique Id'
    -
      name: title
      label: Title
    -
      name: body
      label: 'Post body'
process:
  title: title
  body: body
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
configuration: {  }
```

As you can see the `path: 'public://customfiles/file.csv'` in the YAML structure this is a static way to do the migration. But what I am looking out is dynamically registering our migration. Everyday filename will be changing and I have to fetch the filename and update in YAML dynamically.
I referred [this particular](https://www.webomelette.com/dynamic-migrations-using-templates-drupal-8) link but i didn't get what i was in need of: 
Please suggest a approach for the same. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What about making the code that fetches the new file delete file.csv and fetch the new file, put it in /customfiles folder and rename it to file.csv?

Comment: There is a patch allowing a callback function for the source URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus/issues/3040427

Comment: @NoSssweat, Thanks for your suggestion. But everyday this migration will get importing to website. We have to manage unique dynamic migration id's also to run migration. How can we handle that?

Comment: You can write your own source plugin who's responsible for returning the path. That way it's not hardcoded in the YAML. I've done this for certain dynamic migrations that generate endpoint URLs for external data.